# web scraping get content from xml

Tags: php

how can i use php to get the contents from a xml page.
the content as follows:

```
 <entry>
   <title>News</title>
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://www.website.com/detail/2688327:BlogPost:1569917"/>
     <id>tag:www.website.com,2012-04-25:2688327:BlogPost:1569917</id>
     <updated>2012-04-25T08:30:00.000Z</updated>
     <author>
     <name>Username</name>
     <uri>http://www.website.com/profile/username</uri>
     </author>
      <summary type="html">
      Hi this is the latest news
      </summary>
</entry>

 <entry>
   <title>News2</title>
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://www.website.com/detail/2688327:BlogPost:1569917"/>
     <id>tag:www.website.com,2012-04-25:2688327:BlogPost:1569917</id>
     <updated>2012-04-25T08:30:00.000Z</updated>
     <author>
     <name>Username2</name>
     <uri>http://www.website.com/profile/username</uri>
     </author>
      <summary type="html">
      Hi this is the latest news
      </summary>
</entry>

 <entry>
   <title>News3</title>
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://www.website.com/detail/2688327:BlogPost:1569917"/>
     <id>tag:www.website.com,2012-04-25:2688327:BlogPost:1569917</id>
     <updated>2012-04-25T08:30:00.000Z</updated>
     <author>
     <name>Username3</name>
     <uri>http://www.website.com/profile/username</uri>
     </author>
      <summary type="html">
      Hi this is the latest news
      </summary>
</entry>

 <entry>
   <title>News4</title>
     <link rel="alternate" href="http://www.website.com/detail/2688327:BlogPost:1569917"/>
     <id>tag:www.website.com,2012-04-25:2688327:BlogPost:1569917</id>
     <updated>2012-04-25T08:30:00.000Z</updated>
     <author>
     <name>Username4</name>
     <uri>http://www.website.com/profile/username</uri>
     </author>
      <summary type="html">
      Hi this is the latest news
      </summary>
</entry>
```

How can i get an array of the title , the blog link `<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.website.com/detail/2688327:BlogPost:1569917"/>` , the author details like name and uri(profile link) and the summary out using php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out simplexml, xpath 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

```
   $file = 'url or file name';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('$file');
    $list= $xml->xpath("/entry"); // root/entry ...
    print $list[0]->id; 
    #var_dump($list);
```